# Logging Exceptions with OWIN Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

We have a self-hosted WebAPI application using `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` and I see it logs exception using (ILogger)_logger when an exception is thrown.  Since we are using our own logging framework, how can I supply my own  `ILogger` to `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for us was to set our won 'LoggerFactory'.

```
IAppBuilder appBuilder ............;
..........
appBuilder.SetLoggerFactory(new OwinLoggerFactory());
```

And for 'OwinLoggerFactory':

```
public class OwinLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _baseLoggerFactory;

    public OwinLoggerFactory()
    {
        _baseLoggerFactory=new DiagnosticsLoggerFactory();
    }


    public ILogger Create(string name)
    {
        //create your own OwinLogger class that implements 'ILogger'
        // inside your own OwinLogger class, you may then hook up to any logging Fx you like.
    }
}
```